# Accidentally deleted my target, can't get program to work

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I hit 'backspace' while having selected one of my launch images and then absentmindedly pressed 'okay' before reading the popup dialog. This deleted my target, which apparently cannot be reversed.

So I created a new target with the same name as the old one and had it point to my project file. But when I run my program, it just shows a blank white screen. I checked MainStoryboard.storyboard to find that it had deleted all of my storyboards. Is there any way for me to recover my old MainStoryboard? Or my old Target? I've been trying for the last 30 minutes, looking stuff up online, nothing has worked.

I have an archive of the project from RIGHT before this happened. Is it possible to restore my project from that archive? I haven't created a snapshot since a couple of weeks ago (this was probably stupid of me) so reverting to a snapshot isn't an option.

Any help you can offer me would be greatly appreciated. This is my first iOS app. Not an hour ago I find out that my initial version was rejected from the app store for being too simple. This version had 5 completely new features, I really don't want to have lost it; this entire situation is just so disheartening.

Comment: Xcode never deletes anything. If files appear to be missing, they are either in the project folder (even if they have been excluded from the project itself) or in the trash.

Comment: @matt the only storyboard files in my project folder are blank (they just have one white view). my trash doesn't have any. I manually scrolled through the entire trash and project folder, along with doing a search.

Comment: Did you use SourceControl - like with the default GIT repository?

Comment: @GoZoner I believe that i chose for it to create a local git repository when I started the project, yes.

Comment: @GoZoner but I never manually did a 'commit'. I've never messed with source control before. I suppose I should have. Is my archive file useless in getting my project back? Since I made it when my app was in its last 'good' state (right before I ruined it) it'd be the perfect thing to revert to if I can.

Comment: I find it strange that your MainStoryboard somehow disappeared.  Are you sure that your description of the Target deletion is correct?  I looked into restoring from you archive; it doesn't look possible (but I'm not an expert in that area).

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I tried it again in another project and it left the storyboard untouched, which leads me to believe that something else must have also occurred. But I have no idea what.

Comment: @GoZoner I copied all of my files to a new project to see if I could try to make it work. When I went into one of my files, it was blank. Not only was my storyboard deleted, but a set of .h/.m files was deleted (my initial viewcontroller). All of my other files are left unchanged, but the implementation and header file for my initial viewcontroller has been reset. I'm so confused.

Comment: I was able to mostly recreate my app using the files that remained. Luckily the .h/.m set that were deleted were pretty close to files that remained so I was able to quickly modify them and get what I needed. I'm still upset that this happened, and I'm going to learn to use source control immediately. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Also, get yourself a cheap external HD and set up Time Machine. It will be a lifesaver - trust me.